# Why do some partial fractions have x or a variable in the numerator and others don't?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Why do rational expressions like $\left(\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}\right)$ do not have x in the numerator of the partial fraction but a rational expression like $\left(\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}\right)$ does have x in the numerator of its partial fraction?

Comment: 1. You don't need those big parentheses. 2. What are you talking about??

Comment: if we decomposed both of these rational expressions into partial fractions then the first would have an A+B+C fraction. The second would have Ax+B+Cx+D. These are all fractions btw. Each of these letters has a factor in the denominator that comes from the orginal rational expression. My question is why does the second one have a variable in the numerator for the partial fractions and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate $\frac{1}{(x-2)^k}$ by itself, so it is not necessary to break it into the form $\frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{Bx+C}{(x-2)^2} + \dots.$ On the other hand, $\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^k}$ does not have a simple antiderivative, so we must decompose it into the form $\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2x+3} + \frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} + \dots$

The most general explanation is that $x^2+2x+3$ has complex roots while $x-2$ has real roots. If you allow complex numbers, you can break $\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^k}$ into partial fractions where the numerator is always a constant instead of a term of the form $Ax+B.$